# Redirect all pages to top level page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect all pages on a single URL to the most top level page?

For example, if someone tries to enter http://www.thisdomain.com/sample-sub-page they'll be redirected to http://www.thisdomain.com

The domain in question has a number of Wordpress installations on it so I'd rather not have to edit each instance of WP individually. I assume there's a little htaccess snippet I can use?

I need to be able to redirect ALL requests both ones that link to actual pages and those that are entered in error.

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sample-sub-page/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```